# Java FTPS disabling Certificate Check

Tags: java, ssl, ftps

I need to disable the Certificate check when connecting to a site via FTPS. It seems that the connection is looking for a valid certificate and the one given is already expired. Via WINSCP, we can accept the certificate despite being expired but java won't let me connect.

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredExcept
ion: NotAfter: Fri Mar 31 00:00:00 SGT 2017
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source
)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient.sslNegotiation(FTPSClient.java:
289)
        at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._connectAction_(FTPSClient.java
:220)
        at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient._connect(SocketClient.java:244)
        at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:202)
        at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:306)
        at ftpsdownload.Main.downloadFiles(Main.java:68)
        at ftpsdownload.Main.main(Main.java:38)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Fri Mar 31
00:00:00 SGT 2017
        at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.net.util.TrustManagerUtils$TrustManager.checkServe
rTrusted(TrustManagerUtils.java:61)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(Unkno
wn Source)
        ... 20 more
```

The server manager says that they don't use an SSL so I don't think they know or care about this so I decided to remove it from validation.

Comment: If they don't  use SSL why don't you use FTP instead of FTP**S**?

Comment: My best bet is that FTP can be disabled xD

Comment: Not so sure on that part, they are the client and being one with limited knowledge on these types I cant really suggest they use ftp only

Answer (score 6):

This usually happens when the server accepts ftps connection( not ftp connection). the apache commons net supports FTPS too. use the code below for reference.

1)the encryption of the FTPS server will be either **TLS explicit encryption** or **TLS explicit encryption**.Use the constructor arg for FTPS accordingly.  like

```
      FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient(false);
```

2)if your FTPS server security certificate has expired, disable the check from client by

```
ftpClient.setTrustManager(new X509TrustManager() {
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }

    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
    }
});
```

3)enable file transfer between server and client using this method

```
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

4)use the right port number. Usually for explicit encryption it is 21 and for implicit it is 990

The above four are the common configs required to establish a connection.
The end snippet looks something like this

```
FTPSClient ftpClient = new FTPSClient(false);
        ftpClient.setTrustManager(new X509TrustManager() {
            @Override
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        });
        ftpClient.connect("ftps.mydomain.com",21);
        boolean res = ftpClient.login("username", "password");
        if(!res) throw new Exception("unable to connect to ftps");
        int reply=ftpClient.getReplyCode();
        if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)){
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            FTPFile[] ftpFiles = ftpClient.listFiles("/folder/subfolder");
            System.out.println("complete "+reply+" "+ftpFiles.length);
            for(FTPFile x: ftpFiles){
                System.out.println(x.getName());
            }
            ftpClient.retrieveFile("/folder/subfolder/file.tsv",new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\myname\\Desktop\\out.csv")));
        }else{
            throw new RuntimeException("unable to get valid reply from ftp server. Reply code is "+reply);
        }
```

Comment: It's wrong that you disable the certificate check altogether. You still should check that the certificate is the one you know/expect. Not blindly accept any. You lose a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) this way.